# connect function error QT 5

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, qt5

I have a problems with the connect function in qt, I am a beginner.
Here is my function

```
connect( this->page(), &QWebEngineView::loadFinished(), this, OnPopulateJavaScriptObjects() );
```

I have a class WebView which is where void OnPopulateJavaScriptObjects is declared and implemented .. all functions in one file.  so when I am trying to call this function I am getting this error

```
/home/poker/QTwrapper/main.cpp:40: error: no matching function for call to ‘WebView::loadFinished()’
         connect( this->page(), &QWebEngineView::loadFinished(), this, OnPopulateJavaScriptObjects() );
```

AND SO ON...
So i know  I have a lot of mistakes here... who can help me to explain my mistakes and what can be here the best solution to run this piece of code.

when I am writing connect( this->page(), &QWebEngineView::loadFinished, this, OnPopulateJavaScriptObjects() ); I am getting

```
/home/poker/QTwrapper/main.cpp:40: error: invalid use of void expression connect( this->page(), &QWebEngineView::loadFinished, this, OnPopulateJavaScriptObjects() );
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
connect( this->page(), &QWebEngineView::loadFinished(), this, OnPopulateJavaScriptObjects() );
```

with

```
connect( this->page(), &QWebEngineView::loadFinished, this, &OnPopulateJavaScriptObjects );
```

with `()` you call a method. When you want its address, do call it.

Comment: you still have mistake with your SLOT

Comment: I know but I dont understand what is it, pls can you pls explain , I am trying to solve this already 2 days ((

Comment: I wrote you a solution. You probably also  need to include class name like in signal. Something like: &MyClass::OnPopulateJavaScriptObjects

Comment: WebView web;
 web.connect( web.page(), &QWebEngineView::loadFinished, web, &WebView::OnPopulateJavaScriptObjects );
this gives me this error 
/home/poker/QTwrapper/main.cpp:146: error: no matching function for call to ‘WebView::connect(QWebEnginePage*, void (QWebEngineView::*)(bool), WebView&, void (WebView::*)())’
     web.connect( web.page(), &QWebEngineView::loadFinished, web, &WebView::OnPopulateJavaScriptObjects );
                                                                                                        ^

Comment: OnPopulateJavaScriptObjects is written in WebView class